# Apache Server localhost on mac v.10.10.2 shows password when entering my PHP form

Tags: php, macos, apache, localhost

I created a form to test on my localhost and I noticed when I enter my password in the password field it shows my password. It also shows in the return array after I submit. I am assuming that this is a setting in my php_info(); file, but I'm not sure how to change it. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Just change the `type="text"` to `type="password"` in the input tag of the password field.

This is just a visual restriction (characters not shown) but there is no encryption involved. The form fields will travel in plain text assuming you are accessing that page via http.

If you want the password to travel encrypted you need to access that page via https instead of http.

Comment: Wow I feel like a real dummy. Thanks for your suggestion. As it turns out I did have type="password; however, I forgot my equals '=' sign after type. I must have stuttered.